# Cucumber cannot specify my steps.rb

Tags: ruby, cucumber

having question in scenario execution, my step_definitions can't be specified.
I have install cucumber in my PC as following:

```
cucumber --version
1.3.19
ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08) [i386-mingw32]

..\project1\cucumber Login.feature
```

It always report scenario and steps are undefined.
But my feature is just: (Login.feature)

```
Scenario: Hello IE Scenario
  Given The Action is IE
  Then a browser is open
```

And my steps is (..\project1\step_definitions\Login_steps.rb).

Answer (score 1):

I always use a [features directory](http://www.methodsandtools.com/tools/cucumber.php) that contains the feature files and the step definitions directory

Comment: Do you mean create a new directory contains all feature file and step definition file? I just try with your comments but still shows undefined feature and steps.

Comment: No. features dir holds feature files plus directories with feature files plus a directory with the step definitions called step_definitions plus a directory called support that contains env.rb and other support files. Did you click the link? Try that.